# Obtener valores de una fila obtenida por AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas noches estoy intentando obtener los valores de una fila, donde tengo un botón por cada fila, cuando pulso dicho botón quiero guardar los datos en una variable, para imprimirla después.

Estoy probando así, pero ni tan siquiera recibo el alert con que pulso el botón.

De este modo lleno la tabla, con los registros:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({                        
   type: "GET",                 
   url : "{{URL::to('/extraer-pruebas')}}",
   beforeSend: function() {
      //$('#DataResult').html('<img src="{{ asset("images/gif2.gif")}}" class="loading">');
   },
   timeout:500000,
   success: function(data)            
     {   
      var html = '';
      var i;

      for (i = 0; i < data.pruebas.length; i++) {
        html += 
            `<tr>
                <td class=\"parrafoPruebas\">
                  <span class="namePrueba">${data.pruebas[i].strnombre}</span><br>
                  <p>${data.pruebas[i].strconocido}</p>
                </td>
                <td class=\"noRompe\">${data.pruebas[i].ayuno == 0 ? "<div class=\"ayunoNo\"><i class=\"fas fa-info-circle\"></i> No necesita</div>" : "<div class=\"ayunoSi\"><i class=\"fas fa-info-circle\"></i> Si necesita</div>"}</td>
                <td class=\"center\">${data.pruebas[i].sangreorina == 0 ? "<img src=\"{{ asset('images/svg/drop2.svg') }}\" class=\"tipoPrueba\">" 
                        : data.pruebas[i].sangreorina == 1 ?"<img src=\"{{ asset('images/svg/orinaTA.svg') }}\" class=\"tipoPrueba\">"
                        : data.pruebas[i].sangreorina == 2 ?"<img src=\"{{ asset('images/svg/orisan2.svg') }}\" class=\"tipoPrueba\">"
                        : data.pruebas[i].sangreorina == 3 ?"<img src=\"{{ asset('images/svg/pelo.svg') }}\" class=\"tipoPrueba\">"
                        : data.pruebas[i].sangreorina == 4 ?"<img src=\"{{ asset('images/svg/baston23.svg') }}\" class=\"tipoPrueba\">"
                        : data.pruebas[i].sangreorina == 5 ?"<img src=\"{{ asset('images/svg/baston23.svg') }}\" class=\"tipoPrueba\">" : ""}
               </td>
               <td class=\"noRompe tdOver\"><a href="" class="verPrueba">Ver prueba</a></td>
               <td class="noRompe tdOver"><a id="addPrueba" class="addPrueba">Añadir</a></td>
              </tr>
             `;
            }
             $('#DataResult').html(html)
            }
        });
  });
```

Y estoy probando así:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#addPrueba").click(function() {
     alert("Pulso en añadir");
     var valores = "";
  
     $(".namePrueba").parent("tr").find("td").each(function() {
       if($(this).html() != "coger valores de la fila"){
        valores += $(this).html() + " ";
     }
     });
          
     valores = valores + "\n";
       alert(valores);
     });
});
```

Y lo que quiero obtener es esto: `${data.pruebas[i].strnombre}` que está dentro del span.

---

**No se que opinais así**

```
var carrito = [];
    //$(this).parents("tr").find("td").eq(0).text();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tablaListado').on( 'click', '.addPrueba', function (){
            var valores = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").find("span").eq(0).text();
            carrito.push(valores);
            console.log(carrito); 
           
        });
    });
```

Parece que funciona bien, no se si es la mejor forma, pero no se como hacer para que no pueda añadir dos veces el mismo producto y poder eliminar una fila de las que añado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucione de la siguiente forma, funciona bien.

```
var carrito = [];
    //$(this).parents("tr").find("td").eq(0).text();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tablaListado').on( 'click', '.addPrueba', function (){
            var valores = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").find("span").eq(0).text();
            carrito.push(valores);
            console.log(carrito); 
           
        });
    });
```